# Booting ubuntu from USB drive using grub and then resizing parition

Tags: 14.04, grub2, partitioning, live-usb, gparted

I currently have a dual partition - windows and ubuntu, setup on my computer. However, I would like to resize my ubuntu partition to create more space. I believe to do this from ubuntu I need to unmount my ubuntu partition and run ubuntu from a livedisk/liveusb and then use gparted. I have downloaded ubuntu 14.04 (the version i have on my computer) on to a usb flash drive but for cannot work out how to boot from it. When I load grub I can't see any options to load from USB. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to make sure that you can boot from USB devices in your BIOS options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got your order wrong, that's why it doesn't work.

Instead follow this:

1. Download [gparted live](http://gparted.org/livecd.php) and "burn" that to USB
2. Shut down your machine normally
3. turn it on
4. in your BIOS/UEFI settings, choose to boot the USB (I can't tell you how exactly: this is hardware dependent, look through your BIOS/UEFI manual)
5. Voila: now you can resize the partitions!

## :-)

Comment: As you've never accepted an answer before: if you don't get a better answer in about a week and this one helped you, don't forget to come back and click the little **✓** below the pitifully small number at the left of this text to mark it as a [useful answer](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

After booting from your USB Ubuntu, run the following commands:

Use (or install on your USB live system if it's not already there) gnome-disk-utility.  If it's not already installed, open a terminal and enter `sudo apt-get install gnome-disk-utility` which will install it.  Open it and look to see what disk and partition number your Ubuntu installation is (and make certain that there is "free space" on at least 1 side of the partition as it is unlikely that it would have left open space).  Likely sda2.
Then:
sudo fdisk /dev/(sd?) where ? is the disk letter which has both partitions  which include where your Ubuntu system is installed (the mmcblk0p# is the USB version, so not the one you want to resize - sda is likely the disk your OS's are installed to and sda2 is likely where Ubuntu is).  Then, so long as there actually is free space on either side (before of after the Ubuntu partition) of your Ubuntu partition enter the following (and know that I am presenting this assuming Ubuntu is on sda2:
sudo fdisk /dev/sda/ - Delete the partition Ubuntu is on [note - you are not actually deleting it, but just the partition border record] (d, 2), then re-create it using the defaults (n, p, 2, enter, enter), then write and exit (w). Reboot the computer, then: sudo resize2fs /dev/sda2.
If there is not free space on at least 1 side of your Ubuntu partition then do not do this as you cannot enlarge the partition (you can only do so if there is free space on at least 1 side of the Ubuntu partition).